# How can I debug a solution original in visual studio in vscode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code

My company uses Visual Studio and they relay in the Local IIS debugger in Visual Studio.

However, I would like to use Visual Studio Code instead (and develop in it).
How can I use the debugger in Visual Studio in Visual Studio Code or with a similar function.

One convenient point using the Visual Studio debugger is that it can see the request variable value without logging it and I want to do that in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Launching the program debuggs it for you. But there are also extensions which provide for information.

See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging